# Python - Error while trying to split an input

Tags: python

Hope you're all well, I wanted to use a dictionary that I found on the internet for a code I have but unfortunately, it was not in the format I wanted it to be in therefore I created this little code to help me put all of the 3000 words in my desired format.

The code worked when I inputted words separated by space however it did not work with the words I got from the website because, on the site, every word was put on a different line like So:

```
word 1
 
word 2
```

**Here is my code**, I can't get my head around how I can fix it.

```
wordlist = input ("type the words\n")
wordsSplitted = wordlist.split()
print('"{},"', wordsSplitted )
```

[image: Error Message:]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That error message does not come from Python. You do not have a programming question; you have a "how do I use my computer?" question. To answer it properly, you would need to use https://superuser.com instead, but you would also have to show them, in enough detail for someone else to reproduce the problem, *exactly how you try to run the program*.

Comment: Are you trying to copy and paste the words from the file into your Python input prompt? If so, there are three options that might work better: (1) in a word processor, replace the line endings with spaces, then paste the long string into your prompt. (2) call input() in a loop and add each word to a list. Stop when the user types some signal (blank line, exclamation point, "done!" or whatever you choose. (3) probably the best: save the word list in a text file on your computer and have your Python program open and read that file directly, converting it to a list of words.

Comment: Thank you so much Matthias, my problem was quite hard to explain but you understood what I meant, I will follow your suggestions, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here u can split the words in different lines by a built-in python string function `splitlines()`

```py
wordlist = """Word 1
word 2"""
wordsSplitted = wordlist.splitlines()
print('"{},"', wordsSplitted)
```

This should split lines of your string